# Is every topos equivalent to a full subtopos of U-small objects in another topos?

Tags: category-theory, set-theory, topos-theory

Let $\mathcal{E}$ be a topos, and $\mathcal{U}$ an $\mathcal{E}$-universe (as discussed on [this](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/universe+in+a+topos) nLab page). Let $\mathcal{E}_\mathcal{U}$ be the full subcategory of $\mathcal{U}$-small objects in $\mathcal{E}$. Then I have three questions:

1. Is $\mathcal{E}_\mathcal{U}$ a subtopos for any choice of $\mathcal{U}$?
2. Given topoi $\mathcal{E}$ and $\mathcal{E'}$, we say that $\mathcal{E'}$ *extends* $\mathcal{E}$ when there exists some $\mathcal{E'}$-universe $\mathcal{U}$ such that $\mathcal{E}\simeq\mathcal{E'}_\mathcal{U}$. An extension is called *trivial* when $\mathcal{E}\simeq\mathcal{E'}$. My second question is, does every topos have a nontrivial extension?
3. If 2 holds, then are the extensions of $\mathcal{E}$ totally-ordered by extension? Formally, fix a topos $\mathcal{E}$, and let $[\mathcal{E}]$ be the poset of topoi extending it, where $\mathcal{T}\leq\mathcal{T'}$ exactly when $\mathcal{T'}$ extends $\mathcal{T}$. That this is a poset is immediately obvious, but is it totally-ordered?

I interpret this as asking whether we can always extend a topos to a larger universe without losing the constructions and theorems we started with. It seems like it *should* be true, but I'm very new to topos theory and don't have a lot of trust for my intuitions. Thanks in advance for any help you might offer!

Comment: You can certainly embed every topos in a bigger one by increasing the universe level and taking canonical sheaves, but it is not clear to me whether you can embed them in the way you suggest.

Comment: Would it help to coarsen the level of equivalence required between the subtopos and initial one? In actuality this stuff is happening at the 2-categorical level, so maybe using 1-equivalence is a bit evil. I suppose an appropriate follow-up question is, "just how fine can this equivalence be for the appropriate extension to always exist?"

Comment: That's not the issue. Not every subcategory of a topos that is itself a topos is a subtopos (in either the geometric sense or the logical sense), let alone one that is defined by an "internal" universe.

Comment: I suppose my question was misworded due to my lack of knowledge. Sorry about that. I guess your first reply answered my intended question, then; I was really just curious whether I could extend a topos to a bigger universe when necessary. Thank you.